# JQuery/CSS: Div-overlay and not affect positions of other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

How to make div overlay others div (like.. dropdownlist) and not affect others divs positions?

I've a `#hidden` div that appears when you hover a `#HoverMe div`, unhover it and it hides again. 
But that div moves others div when hovered.

1. How to make hidden-div overlay other div?
2. how do I make that hidden-div not affecting others div position?

how it's like:

```
    ------    ------   ------
   |  1  |  |   2   | |  3   |  //#HoverMe div is not hovered
    ------   -------   ------
             ______
    ------  |      |  -------   ------
    |  1  | |Affect| |   2   | |  3   |  ////#HoverMe div is hovered, affects others div positions
    ------  |      |  -------   ------
             ------
```

**What I want**

```
             ______
    ------  |  No  |----   ------
    |  1  | |Affect| 2  | |  3   |  //Just overlay, without affecting others divs positions
    ------  |      |---   ------
             ------
```

**My code:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#HoverMe").hover(function(){
        $("#hidden").css('display', 'block');
    }, function() {
        $("#hidden").css('display', 'none');
        }
    );

});
</script>
```

I use my `#HoverMe`-div to show `#hidden`-div that have a list of content I want to show.

```
 <div id="HoverMe" >
     This owner own @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TotCar) cars in total
 </div>              

 <div id="hidden" style="background-color: black"> //<------- hidden
     @foreach (var car in Model.Car) { 
         <div>@car.Name</div> 
      }
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you only need `position:absolute` ?

Comment: @Flink Awesome it works! So simple.

Comment: Wrap all the elements, including the hidden element in a `<div>` styled with `position: relative;` and then style the hidden element with `position: absolute;` and set the `top` and `left` properties (relative to the enclosing `<div>`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks!

Comment: @StephenMuecke You know any good way to make `Hidden` div appear right under `HoverMe` div, regardless where HoverMe div is?

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:absolute` to `#hidden` div and it should work.

Comment: This is the correct answer. OP should accept.