# CSS/JQuery: Make div appear next to another (with absolute position)

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I've a `#hidden` div that appears when `#HoverMe` is hovered, unhover it and it hides again. The `#hidden` have its sub-div which act like a dropdownlist.
`#hidden`uses `position: absolute;`.How do I force `#hidden` div to appear next to `#HowerMe`, and let its sub-div(inside `#hidden` div) appear under?

**how it's working now:**

```
                          ------------     
                         |  #HoverMe   |                            
                          ------------    
  ---------
 | #hidden |
 | --------|
 | car.name|        
 |---------|
 | car.name|  
  ---------
```

**How I want**

```
                      ------------     ---------
                     |  #HoverMe   |  | #hidden |                           
                      ------------    | --------|
                                      | car.name|        
                                      |---------|
                                      | car.name|  
                                       ---------
```

**My code:**
I use my `#HoverMe`-div to show `#hidden`-div that have a list of content I want to show.

```
<div style="position: relative">
     <div id="HoverMe" >
         This owner own @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TotCar) cars in total
     </div>              

     <div id="hidden" style="position: absolute; display: none; background-color: black"> //<------- hidden
         @foreach (var car in Model.Car) { 
             <div>@car.Name</div> 
          }
    </div>
 </div>


<script>
     var hoverEle = $("#HoverMe");
        var popupEle = $("#hidden");    

        function hidePopup() {
            $("#hidden").hide();
        }

        $('#HoverMe, #hidden').hover(function () {
            $("#hidden").stop(true).show();
        }, function () {
            $("#hidden").stop(true).delay(2000).fadeOut();
        });
```

Comment: Do you have to use `position:absolute` ? There are many ways to achieve what you want without using absolute positionsing.

Comment: @JonP If I don't use `absolute`, then it will disturb other divs positions. So far I can only manage to avoid that by `absolute`, don't know other way.

Comment: What other divs? Do you want the "car list" appearing on top of other content?

Comment: @JonP I've other divs around `#HoverMe` div, and `#hidden` div moves other when it appears, that's why I've to use absolute to avoid that. I want "Car list" to appear where `#hidden` starts in my illustration.

Comment: Is [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ayhph741/) what your wanting? (set the `left` and `top` properties to position it relative to the containing `<div>`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, that what I was looking for. Much obliged.

Comment: I did explain that in one of your [previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931998/jquery-css-div-overlay-and-not-affect-positions-of-other-divs) :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Aah dang, my mistake! I adjusted my code a lot since then and I got tunnel vision and confused so my memory didn't rang a bell.. Thanks again :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Just a last question, e.g. if the output from `hidden` div is to long like "`this owner owns Volvo`", it breaks the output in middle and and says "`this owner owns`" (new line) "`Volvo`". Setting `width: Xpx`" works, but I think that's ineffective, is there some way to set "`width:`" to auto ?

Comment: Without seeing more details, I can't be sure what you rendering (a fiddle would help). But it will wrap if the width of `#hidden` plus the `left` amount is greater than the with of the containing `<div>`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `display: inline-block;` to make hidden `div` be displayed as you want. You don't even need to set `position` to `absolute`.

Some advices

1. Use

   ```html
       <ul>
         <li>Item 1</li>
         <li>Item 2</li>
         <li>Item 3</li>
         <li>Item 4</li>
       </ul>
   ```

in order to display lists.

2. When you saved an element into variable, you can use this variable instead of calling `$()` one more time.

   ```
   var hoverEle = $("#HoverMe");
   var popupEle = $("#hidden");    

   function hidePopup() {
     popupEle.hide(); // indeatd of $("#hidden").hide();
   }

   hoverEle.hover(function () {
     popupEle.stop(true).show();
   }, function () {
     popupEle.stop(true).delay(2000).fadeOut();
   });
   ```

Here is the working demo:

```js
var hoverEle = $("#HoverMe");
var popupEle = $("#hidden");    

popupEle.hide();

hoverEle.hover(function() {
  popupEle.fadeIn();
}, function() {
  popupEle.fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}

#HoverMe {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: green;
}

#hidden {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="HoverMe" >
    This owner own
  </div>

  <ul id="hidden">
    <li>Car1</li>
    <li>Car2</li>
    <li>Car3</li>
    <li>Car4</li>
    <li>Car5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In one page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test app</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <style type="text/css">
  .wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   text-align: left;
  }

  #HoverMe {
   display: inline-block; // in order to make div behave as inline element
   vertical-align: top;
   width: 200px;
   height: 60px;
   background-color: green;
  }

  #hidden {
   width: 200px;
   display: inline-block; // in order to make div behave as inline element
   margin: 0;
   vertical-align: top;
   background-color: black;
   color: white;
  }
 </style>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div id="HoverMe" >
   This owner own
  </div>

  <ul id="hidden">
   <li>Car1</li>
   <li>Car2</li>
   <li>Car3</li>
   <li>Car4</li>
   <li>Car5</li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   console.log("ready");
   var hoverEle = $("#HoverMe");
   var popupEle = $("#hidden");    
   
   popupEle.hide();

   hoverEle.hover(function() {
    popupEle.fadeIn();
   }, function() {
    popupEle.fadeOut();
   });
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd also suggest to use var names with first `$` for those jQuery objects: `var $hoverElement = $("#HoverMe");` and `var $popup = $("#hidden");`.

Comment: The positions is correct now but I can't make it work like my JQuery code. I want to hide the `#hidden` div when the page run as you did, but when I hover `#HowerMe` and I try move the mouse to `#hidden` div, it will still disappear. I tried to implement my code without success. **Edit:** What I mean, I want to stop `#hidden` to disappear when I hover it. If I leave, then it will disappear.

Comment: You should just simply bind hover function not to `#HowerMe` element but to `warpper` element. In the demo change `hoverEle.hover` to `$('.wrapper').hover` and #hidden div will not disappear.

Comment: You could add `position: absolute` to `wrapper` element and it would not disturbs other divs position.